# Does Firestore require a separate index for EVERY combination of queried fields? (9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement logic for querying people collections for suggestion of names based on a combination of arguments of 3 possible (`name`, `surname`, `nick`), eg:

```
people.where('name', '==', nameArg).where('surname', '>=', surnameArg).where('surname', '<=', surnameArg + '\uf8ff')
```

or

```
people.where('nick', '==', nickArg).where('name', '>=', nameArg).where('name', '<=', nameArg+ '\uf8ff')
```

The idea is that there might be any 1 or 2 fields using `==` operator and one with `>=` / `<=`. I got the error `9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.`, so I created an index using all 3 of the fields. But when my query uses only 2 of the fields I still get the same error.

Am I expected to create 4 indices for every combination of query parameters? This feels so wrong.

Does the order of fields in the index matter too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you'll often end up with many indexes on your Firestore project, you may not need a composite index for each combination of fields. They key here is that Firestore can use the single-field indexes for equality checks.

From the documentation on [taking advantage of index merging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview):

> Although Cloud Firestore uses an index for every query, it does not necessarily require one index per query. For queries with multiple equality (`==`) clauses and, optionally, an orderBy clause, Cloud Firestore can re-use existing indexes. Cloud Firestore can merge the indexes for simple equality filters to build the composite indexes needed for larger equality queries.

I must admit I always struggle a bit with how to apply this on my own projects, but for example the FriendlyEats sample project uses surprisingly few [indexes](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android/blob/master/firestore.indexes.json) for the amount of [sorting and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#8) it allows.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying that I should simply create an index for each of the fields? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I am confused, because from the docs and Firestore's interface I conclude that single field indices are created automatically by default. But I do get that error so it does not seem to work this way?

Comment: The use of multiple single-field indexes only works for **equality** filters. Other types of filters and sorting always require a composite index on the involved field, but you can add more equality checks to your query without adding separate indexes for those.

Comment: This means that using unequality filter combined with equality filters does after all require indices for all possible combinations of equality - nonequality fields. And not only that - also all order combinations! I just tried querying `surname-name` having and index for `name-surname` and it still throws that error! :o I really fail to understand why Firebase is so popular.